How to clear GPU in training loop using Keras?
I've been exploring methods to train multiple models within a single codebase. The aim is to generate various models using different seeds to assess diverse architectures and training data. The data is generated with random seeds to allow for varied data splits. However, I've encountered discrepancies in the results between training a single model and training a set of models. I suspect that the initial model's training may influence subsequent training sessions. Is there a way to ensure complete independence between the training processes of each model?
This is the part of my code where I build and train the Model:
    def build_model(self,seed):
    models = []
    print("Creating Model With Seed:", seed)
    regularizer = keras.regularizers.L1L2(l1=1e-5,l2=1e-4)
    initializer = keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=seed)
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Input(shape=self.input_shape),
        layers.Dense(6, activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer = initializer,kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
        layers.Dense(1, activation = 'linear',kernel_initializer = initializer)
    ])

    model.compile(loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: self.huber_loss(y_true, y_pred, delta=0.35),
                    optimizer= 'adam',
                    metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    return model

        # 1.12 Model Training

def train_models(self, model, seed, epochs, batch_size):
    early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=50)
    histories = []
    print("Training Model With Seed Number:", seed)

    for i, seed in enumerate(self.seeds):
        # Train the model
        history = model.fit(
            self.normed_train_data[i],
            self.train_labels[i],
            epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, batch_size=batch_size,
            callbacks=[PrintDot(), early_stop]
        )
        histories.append(history)
        # Reset the random seed for TensorFlow operations back to its default value
        # tf.random.set_seed(None)
        return histories


Hi @Agenor Maradiaga,To ensure complete independence between the training processes of each model, you can take several steps:
Reset TensorFlow's Random Seed: After each model's training, reset TensorFlow's random seed to its default value. This ensures that subsequent models start with a clean slate in terms of random initialization.
Reset Model Weights: Optionally, you can reset the weights of the model after each training session to ensure that subsequent models start from the same initial weights.
